# Is it possible to reference an assembly depending on the solution configuration?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I know I can reference an assembly depending on the *project* configuration, but can I do it based on the *solution* configuration? I'm thinking of something like this:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(SolutionConfiguration)' == 'Debug1'>
  <Reference Include="Library1">
    <HintPath>C:\Path\To\Library1.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(SolutionConfiguration)' == 'Debug2'>
  <Reference Include="Library2">
    <HintPath>C:\Path\To\Library2.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

If not like this, is there any other way I can reference one or another assembly depending on the solution configuration?

Comment: This should work. Try Configuration instead of SolutionConfiguration

Comment: @RicoSuter I did, but Configuration refers to the project configuration, not the solution configuration.

Comment: As a side not, absolute paths like `C:\Path\To\Library2.dll` are evil. If you think maintaining all of this now is challenging, just wait until you check out from source control on a different dev box or a build server.

Comment: @3Dave I agree, and in a real project I would define an environment variable with the path to the library. The library is provided by a third-party vendor. The assemblies are not in the GAC and are not available via NuGet.

Comment: There are also some config variables that you can use to get the solution dir, project dir, etc. Or just use a relative path. :D I never put anythying in the GAC. It invites the .NET version of DLL hell. One thing Apple got right is that all app dependencies live in the application's folder. Uninstall == delete.

Answer (score 0):

Solution configurations are linked to project configurations. For each solution configuration, we specifiy which project configurations to use. For example, when we select solution Release, projects Release are typically selected.

So create two project configurations matching the two solution configurations you want for the dll you want. When you select a solution configuration, different project configurations will be selected and the correct dll will de referenced.

Comment: That's actually how I have it set up right now, but I wanted to find a way to avoid having to create all these project configurations (for both Debug and Release) for every solution configuration.

Comment: An alternative would be to load the dll dynamically based on some configuration parameters.